# Add iOS MTKView to dotnet maui ContentPage

Tags: maui

In our dot net maui application we have the following ContentPage

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
   <ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="App.Maui.VideoPage"
         Title="VideoPage">
   <VerticalStackLayout>
 
   </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

We would like to add a native view inside the VerticalStackLayout. For example on iOS
we would use a MetalKit MTKView derived class which is only available in our native library. How can we add such a view. We would then render video into this view.

Thanks

Comment: See [Create custom controls with handlers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/handlers/create?view=net-maui-7.0). If you run into trouble, add to question the code, and explain what goes wrong. This is an advanced topic; don't get discouraged!

Comment: Thanks but that example uses classes such as AVPlayer. I think I need to use iOS binding library to create a dotnet  version of the objective c classes I need

Comment: I don't know about that part. Whatever you do, you'll still need to know how to add the resulting view to Maui's view hierarchy; that's the part I've answered.

Comment: Yes, in addition to the bindings, the stuff in that link needs to be done as well

Comment: I've never done this, but if you can't find info for Maui, it should be similar to xamarin. Search `xamarin bind to ios native`.